# Asking about SSRS expression font change

Tags: service, reportng

I have an expression like this:

```html
Fields!PRODNAME.Value & vbcrl
Fields!ADDRESS.Value & vbcrlf &
Fields!CITY.Value + " ," + Fields!STATE.Value & vbcrlf &
Fields!PINCODE.Value & vbcrlf &
```

In the above I want to bold the first field, and leave the remaining text in a normal font.

Comment: -Edit- Shhhh.... Stop yelling at us!

Answer (score 0):

What version of SSRS are you using?

If you have 2012, you can use **HTML** tags in a text box **placeholder** to add formatting:

```
"<b>" & Fields!PRODNAME.Value "</b>" & vbcrl
Fields!ADDRESS.Value & vbcrlf &
Fields!CITY.Value + " ," + Fields!STATE.Value & vbcrlf &
Fields!PINCODE.Value & vbcrlf &
```